# Trying to copy one of gameObjects rotation elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to get the x rotation of a gameObject and then assigning another gameObjects z rotation to that, code here:

```
var r = (target.transform.rotation);
Debug.Log(r);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.position.y, r.x);
```

The Debug.Log() only gives decimals in a Quaternion and this messes up the transform.rotaion in the last line,
How would I get the actual rotation of the gameObject and assign it to my transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something odd about your third line,

```cs
    Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.position.y, r.x);
```

Your first and third argument for Euler() is transform.rotation, but the second is transform.position. This is the reason the result maybe unexpected.

On a side note you are not allowed to directly set or modify your **transform.rotation** as explained in the documentation in https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html

Instead:

> To rotate a Transform, use Transform.Rotate, which uses Euler Angles.

The method Transform.Rotate() takes in a Vector3 parameter so, in your case, declare it as

```cs
var rotateAmount = new Vector3(
            transform.rotation.x, 
            transform.rotation.y, 
            target.transform.rotation.x);
```

Then apply the transformation like:

```cs
transform.rotate(rotateAmount, Space.Self);
```

Second argument for transform.rotate() can be Space.World if you want the rotation to happen based on the global axis instead.

Comment: I changed the position to make it rotation but that didn't solve anything, I then tried using the code that you suggested and it didn't work, it just continually rotates

Comment: **"it just continually rotates"**. 

Something about this tells me that your code is in a game loop which is why it keeps rotating. Double check to make sure that's not the case because this rotate should apply only once.

Comment: Yeah it is in the fixedUpdate() function, how should I have it called?

Comment: `On a side note you are not allowed to directly set or modify your transform.rotation as explained` is not true! Of course you are allowed and most of the time directly modify the `transform.rotation` by assigning a new `Quaternion` to it! The `Rotate` is just a suggestion ... it rotates form he current rotation while setting `rotation` overwrites the overall resulting rotation ... the entire second part of your answer is quite invalid as OP does want to copy not sum up the rotation of the other object

Comment: @derHugo thanks for the correction, but it still holds that its better to use Unity's inbuilt function of Rotate to remove the complexity that comes along with Quaternions. This answer has a good explanation of the pros and cons of both: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57528969/17985195)